# Additional keys were returned from `getServerSideProps`. Return notFound object from getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have next app. I need to realize logic when route is not match in [slug] page then show 404 page error.

In next as far as I know for show 404 page I need to return `notFound` object with value `true`.[Link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)

So the question  is when I return `{ notFound: true }` from `getServerSideProps` why I get this error?

> Error: Additional keys were returned from `getServerSideProps`.
> Properties intended for your component must be nested under the
> `props` key, e.g.:
>
> return { props: { title: 'My Title', content: '...' } }
>
> Keys that need to be moved: notFound.

Code:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ params, req }) => {

    const { slug } =  params;

    // first request
    const data = await (await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST}/${slug}`)).json();

    // second request
    const user = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "jwt",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });
    const userInfo = await user.json();


    if ( !slug || data.statusCode === 404 ) return { notFound: true }

    return {
        props: {
            title: "something",
            // my props in here
        },
    }
}
```

It gives error only when I write something in `url` and change my slug page consciously from correct to incorrect. For example from `localhost/page/1` to `localhost/page/blablabla`.

In this case when I change route to wrong works this if case `(if ( !slug || data.statusCode === 404 ) )`.Next version 9.5.2

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that gives you an error? It looks fine, apart from weird awaits, but it should work as expected. What version of Next are you using?

Comment: @Danila It gives error only when I write something in url and change my slug page consciously  from correct to incorrect. For example from `localhost/page/1` to  `localhost/page/blablabla`.In this case when I change route to wrong works this if case  `(if ( !slug || data.statusCode === 404 ) )`.Next version 9.5.2. Updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Next version 9.5.2. The earliest version that supports `notFound` is 10.0.0. From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering):

[image: >v10.0.0 locale, locales, defaultLocale, and notFound options added.]

So you have to upgrade to use that logic.